# connect to another instance of the aplication on the local network in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am trying to implement a server/clint java application. Once the server socket is listening on port 3232, I would like to client to automatically browse the network and scan each IP address in the subnet till it finds another instance (server) that is running on port 3232 and then report it's IP address so I can use it in the application to set as the socket connection destination IP address.

I have been suggested to use exec(nmap) to scan the network for the open port but I want to deploy this application on systems where do not have nmap installed.

If I understand correctly, I have to make a for loop to iterate through the host to finally find the right host whose port 3232 is open.

```
public static ArrayList<InetAddress> checkHosts(int socket, int timeout)
{
ArrayList<InetAddress> al = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();
try
{
    byte[] buffer = {1};
    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(socket);
    ds.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    DatagramPacket dp;
    InetAddress local = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String subnet = getSubnet(local);
    System.out.println(subnet);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        String host = subnet + i;
        try {
            ds.send(new DatagramPacket(buffer, 1, InetAddress.getByName(host), 3232));
            ds.receive(dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 1));
            if(dp.getPort() == socket && !dp.getAddress().equals(local))
                al.add(dp.getAddress());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

return al;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if the server sends some multicast messages periodically? Each client and other servers can receive them and will know about the server's existance.

Comment: I want to keep things as simple as possible

Comment: Oh, of course it is simpler to hammer a nail into the wall with a screwdriver instead of using the tool which is exactly made for that use case ;-)